# JQuery Dragging and Scrolling with Easing

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, draggable, easing

Does anyone know of any script JQuery  or other to Drag and Scroll with easing?

I have found various scripts to scroll smoothly with easing, or drag smoothly with easing. But the scripts that scroll and drag all seem to not include easing. Here are some examples:

Utterscroll
https://github.com/debiki/utterscroll

DragOn
http://dragon.deparadox.com/

DragScrollable
    http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html
    http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollsync.js
    http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/dragscrollable.js

If anyone knows of a dragging-scrolling script with easing, please let me know. Alternatively we may need to integrate easing into one of the above scripts, but these are pretty complicated scripts to mess around with.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked these out?

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/

They don't exactly support "easing" but they simulate some kind of velocity and resistance...

Comment: I guess this answered your question then? if so, could you mark it as answered? Thanks :)

Comment: I have install iScroll, the previous and current version, but am finding all sorts of issues. Check out my new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352639/horizontal-iscroll-issues-on-desktop-brows

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest iscroll4. There is also a really unique touch implementation by Simurai http://simurai.com/post/31460815120/flick-scroll ( It is trying to find a desiccant gesture for long mobile scrolling, more a UX approach of your problem )

Comment: This is pretty neat, but I think users are not going to master the subtleties of the two gesture types.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery Custom Scrollbar: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Easy to setup, has a great set of customizable options, plus an API for callbacks.